# Запись одним запросом

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

В прошлом вопросе мне дали утвердительный ответ, который я и так знал. Немного поразмыслив, пришел к этому:

```
$res = "INSERT INTO SC_products (categoryID, Price, in_stock, enabled, product_code, name_en,brief_description_en,description_en,meta_title_en,meta_description_en,meta_keywords_en,slug,name_ru,brief_description_ru,description_ru,meta_title_ru,meta_description_ru,meta_keywords_ru,ordering_available) VALUES (" . implode("), (", $arr) . ")";  
mysqli_query($link, $res);
```

Вопрос: что я не так делаю, почему данные не записываются в базу?

Comment: Так вы выведете запрос на экран и выполните его ручками в клиенте mysql, там и ошибку увидите.

А вообще, в PHP для этого уже все предусмотрели: [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: И опять же - какая локализация в базе? Вам пример привести, когда этот ваш способ локализации начнет с ошибками работать (для InnoDB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ("Cardinal", "Stavanger", "Norway")
```

**обновлено:**

Ваш запрос после `implode` выглядит так:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES (Cardinal), (Stavanger), (Norway)
```

Вывод: не хватает кавычек внутри `implode`, а также первой и последней пары скобок:

Пример:

```
$res = "INSERT INTO SC_products (categoryID, Price, in_stock, enabled, product_code, name_en,brief_description_en,description_en,meta_title_en,meta_description_en,meta_keywords_en,slug,name_ru,brief_description_ru,description_ru,meta_title_ru,meta_description_ru,meta_keywords_ru,ordering_available) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $arr) . "')";
```

Comment: А если он вставляет несколько значений? Например:

    function to_row($data) {
        return implode(",", $data);
    }

    $array = array(
        array(1, "first"),
        array(2, "second"),
    );
    $arr = array_map('to_row', $array);
    echo "INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (" . implode("), (", $arr) . ")";

Выведет `INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1,first), (2,second)`, что неправильно из-за отсутствия кавычек на строках, а не из-за скобок

Comment: @BOPOH, вы совершенно правы. Некорректно развернул в голове пример автора. К сожалению, вы тоже ошиблись в причинах ошибки. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Не, почему же я не правильно указал? )) Я не знаю, что лежит в $arr, там, может, в нормальном виде все лежит. Мой комментарий относился к моему примеру, хотя он и на запроса автора скорее всего тоже распространяется:

Развернутый запрос автора будет не `VALUES (Cardinal"), ("Stavanger"), ("Norway)`, а `VALUES (Cardinal), (Stavanger), (Norway)`, т.к. внутри implode он кавычки не указал ) А те, что указал - только для обозначения строки используются.

Т.е. правильно будет:

    $sql = "...('" . implode("'), ('", $arr) . "')";

Comment: А для того, чтобы, не зная значения $arr, понять причину, достаточно просто вывести сгенерированный запрос и визуально (или в клиенте mysql) проверить его. Потому мой комментарий к вопросу и просил это сделать.

Здесь возможны ошибки: те же скобки, кавычки, либо типы полей не совпадают, либо сработало ограничение InnoDB на строки (почему я и против локализации через DB), либо он просто к базе не подключился и т.д.

Одно дело, когда "есть запрос, mysql выдает ошибку, почему", другое дело - "у меня тут куча всего, записи не добавляются, вот кусочек кода, что не так". Надо учить отлаживать код )

Comment: @BOPOH, вы дважды правы. :) Сегодня я и сам с кавычками не в ладах.

Comment: Спасибо @ВОРОН большое за развернутый ответ 
$arr = array_map('to_row', $array); нужно выносить за цикл?

Comment: @ggLike, я не знаю, что у вас в цикле, поэтому подсказать не могу. `array_map` я использовал, чтобы вставлять несколько записей одновременно без цикла, поэтому не совсем понимаю, где вы его хотите использовать